# How do I hide resource folders for other Maven build profiles in Netbeans?

Tags: maven, netbeans-8

I've got a Maven project which has two build profiles. These build profiles have different resource directories.

When I work with any of these two build profiles, NetBeans show all resource directories. I'd like to only see the resource directories related to the current build profile.

Looking at the below picture, only `src/main/resources` and `src/main/resources-server` is defined for the build profile. The `resources-client` folder is defined for the other build profile. However, regardless of which build profile I choose, NetBeans show them all.

Is there a way around this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like you should have separated projects one server and a client instead of using profiles etc.

Comment: Thats a different discussion though...